# my xml file showing error saying - "Content is not allowed in trailing section."

Tags: android-contentresolver

my xml file showing error saying - "Content is not allowed in trailing section." on eclipse.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>  
    <string name="app_name">MyContentProvider</string> 
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>  
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>  
 </resources>;
```

How to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolon `;` at the end:

```
</resources>;
```

change into:

```
</resources>
```